# SQL Server and Agent Services not starting automatic in AZURE IaaS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, azure

We migrated an on-premise database to azure IaaS and the machines is on between 7am and 7pm that way we save money in the night when the users are not querying the database, but every time the machine goes up at 7am sql server services and the agent don't get started automatically, we have tried setting the startup tyme to automatic and automatic(Delayed start) but it still not working, any ideas of what we should check to make this happen and not having to start the services manually?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a domain account for the service?  Is your DC up and working *before* you start the SQL Server?  Does a mid-day restart have the same issue?

Comment: @JonathanFite im using a domain account, DC is working 24-7, if I restart the server in the middle of the day it works with delayed start